# mysql innodb ibd file space usage

Tags: mysql, innodb, space

I have a innodb table, and set mysql innodb_file_per_table=1 on Host A

this table's ibd file allocate about 3GB disk

then, i dump this table to sql file(a.sql), a.sql allocate about 2.5Gb disk

next, i import a.sql to Host B.

Host A and Host B have the same hardware, same system, same mysql configure.

But i found, this table's ibd file on Host B allocate 30GB disk.

i try to dump this table on Host B to b.sql

b.sql have the same size of a.sql.

I am sure after the import a.sql to Host B, we don't have alert table action.

Why the allocate disk so large? thanks.

table description:

[image]

Comment: When i run "show table status", i found this table: "InnoDB free: 22813696 kB". Is there any way to release "InnoDB free space" ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have ibdata1 there? What is the result after you run optimize table a on Host A? It may be because in host A, some of your data of table A is inside the file ibdata1.